# Postgresql: definition of own type in C

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm using a Postgresql 9.2 installation and I'm trying to get an extension (I have programmed)  to run.

This code compiles, and I can load it into Postgresql; but every time I try to do an `INSERT`, the connection to the DB stops. I guess the reason for that is that my `in`-function is somehow broken.

First to the typedef:

```
typedef struct tphys {
   char   length[4];
   char   data[1];
} tphys;
```

As you see, I have a data-type that is meant to be unlimited in size. And now to the `in`-code:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(tphys_data_in);
Datum
tphys_data_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
   char *in  = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
   tphys *dest = (tphys *) palloc(VARHDRSZ + VARSIZE(in));

   SET VARSIZE(dest, VARHDRSZ + VARSIZE(in));
   memcpy(VARDATA(dest), in, VARSIZE(in));

   PG_RETURN_POINTER(dest);
}
```

I've been trying with this code quite some time, and I really don't know where the error is. Do you maybe see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use VARSIZE macro for cstring type.

```
char *instr = PG_GETAR_CSTRING(0);
tphys *dest = (phhys *) palloc(VARHDRSZ + strlen(instr));

...
```